# Jade no longer accepting inline variables without JavaScript delineation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

When I used Jade in version 0.34.1 (prior to version 1.0.0), I was able to use inline variables such as:

```
test = 'fun'
p #{test}
```

Which would normally output:

```
<p>fun</p>
```

But now outputs:

```
<test>= 'fun'</test>
<p></p>
```

It appears this might have changed in version 1.0.0; although, I see no documentation describing the change (https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/History.md#100--2013-12-22).

If I use the JavaScript delineation, it works:

```
- test = 'fun'
p #{test}
```

I assume this is because The JavaScript delineation is now required.

I ran these tests both locally using grunt-contrib-jade version 0.9.1 and at http://jade-lang.com/demo/.

---

Is there any way to change this and are there any confirmed findings of why this change occurred in the first place?

## EDIT

Thanks to @Jonathan Lonowski for pointing out it was noted in [Remove special assignment syntax](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/History.md#100--2013-12-22).

Comment: The change is mentioned as: "[*Remove special assignment syntax*](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/History.md#100--2013-12-22)." And, the `-` operator is no longer optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [changeset](https://github.com/pugjs/jade/blob/master/History.md#100--2013-12-22), the `-` operator is no longer optional.

From now on, always include `-` before JavaScript in Jade:

```jade
- test = 'fun'
p #{test}
```

> Thanks goes to @Jonathan Lonowski for this information.